# What will be the true integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

As the integration of $x(x^2+1)$ can be $x^4 /4 + x^2 /2 + c$ and it also can be $\frac{1}{4} (x^2+1)^2+C$.

Comment: I do not see how ODE is related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same. Note that $x^4/4+x^2/2+c=\frac{1}{4}(x^4+2x^2+1)+(c-1/4)$.